# Почему в сессии codeigniter записываются верные данные только после вывода сессии?

Tags: php, сессия, codeigniter

Использую 4 codeigniter. Нужно при первом заходе на страницу записать в сессию код и потом, при отправке формы пользователем, сравнить этот код с тем, что находится в сессии. Для проверки вывожу сессию во `view` и оно совпадает с кодом, однако значение из сессии для сравнения оказывается записывается какое-то другое и непонятно откуда взявшееся. Я и сессию чистил, и `Flashdata` использовал, и останавливал и по новой запускал сессию, всё равно записывается случайное значение. Однако, если принудительно из контроллера вывести сессию `var_dump`-ом или просто перезапустить страницу, чтобы значение перезаписалось, то сравниваются 2 нужных кода и всё срабатывает. В чём может быть проблема? В конструкторе сессия подключена.

Функции контроллера:

```
public function __construct()
{
  $this->session = \Config\Services::session();
}

public function index()
{
  $userCode = $this->request->getPost("userCode");
  $codeSession = $this->session->get("code");
  if(!empty($userCode))
  {
    if($userCode == $codeSession)
    {
      return redirect()->to('/Home');
    }else{
      // Для проверки значений. При первом посте - мусор, при последующих нужный код
      var_dump($codeSession);
    }
  }else{
    // Тут даже при первом заходе на страницу уже есть код почему-то
    $this->session->has("code") ? $this->session->remove("code") : '';
  }
  
  $this->generateCode();
  $data['codeSession'] = $this->session->get("code");
  // var_dump($this->session->get()); -> Так сработает и при первом запуске.
  // Без вывода надо перезапустить страницу чтобы код опять переприсвоился.
  return view("/pageWithCode", $data['codeSession']);
}

private function generateCode()
{
  $code = "Some random code";
  $this->session->set("code", $code);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Проблема в иконке favicon**, а точнее в её отсутствии по заданному пути в `head` при отрисовке страницы:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/assets/favicon/favicon.ico">
```

Немного переформулирую. Причина была в том, что при попытке загрузить иконку, codeigniter бросал исключение в классе фильтра.

Будь это обычная страница, был бы редирект на страницу с приведённым контроллером, а поскольку это был файл, который не мог подгрузиться, происходило всего лишь выполнение кода и перезапись данных в сессии без редиректа.

А причина того, что всё срабатывало при выводе данных из контроллера через `var_dump` в том, что `head` не подгружался и codeigniter не бросал исключение на подключение этого файла.

Примерно похожая проблема может возникнуть, если в фильтрах у вас стоит разрешение на переход неавторизованным (к примеру) пользователем на страницу `example` в которую что-либо подгружается со страницы `example/someData`, на которую у вас разрешение не подключено. Например так:

```
<?php

namespace Config;

use CodeIgniter\Config\BaseConfig;

class Filters extends BaseConfig
{
    public $globals = [
        'before' => [
            'csrf' => [
                'except' => [
                    'example'
                 ]
            ],
        ],
        'after' => [],
    ];
}
```

Чтобы эту проблему избежать надо после `'example'` дописать `, 'example/someData'`. Либо же сделать `'example/*'`, что откроет доступ ко всем файлам по этому пути.